# iOS performFetchWithCompletionHandler at specific time (Schedule)

Tags: ios

I want to trigger web service at 12 am daily (as an example). Can it be done?

I have studied about background fetch and I found out this one.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler
```

Problem is that system will decide when to trigger. I need to make scheduled web service. How shall I do?

Edit :

I am doing for enterprise app and I don't need to submit to App Store. I guess I can still use private api (if it is necessary).

Answer (score 0):

I'm was dealing with the same problem. But in my case time does not have to be that precise so I was able to use background fetch, but you can use push notifications.

Basically what you can do is instead of using background fetch to use remote notifications in silent mode. Take a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3) (search for "Using Push Notifications to Initiate a Download").

By default when you send payload to APNS you will receive notification, but if you just send JSON with:

```
{content-available:1, sound:""}
```

you will trigger delegate method, but no change on your UI, so there you can implement your business logic.

Only downside is that you will need to maintain device tokens and to have additional service which will communicate with your application and with the APNS to send these notifications.